# Type 'ClassA<{ id: number; name: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'ClassA<Record<string, any>>'

Tags: typescript, conditional-statements, typeerror, typescript-generics

I have a ClassA which should only allow objects as value type. But it should be possible to pass your  own object type as generic type. Accomplished with `Record<string, any>` or `{ [key: string]: any }`.
Works everything as expected.

But as soon as I try to extract the ClassA generic type with a simple condition type.

```
class ClassA<DataType = Record<string, any>>{
    public data: { [key: string]: ClassB<DataType> };
    constructor(){
      this.data = {};
    }
}

type NonArrayType<T> = T extends ClassA<infer U> ? U[] : never;

// Test function to test the 'NonArrayType' type
export function useWithoutArray<X extends ClassA>(
  deps: X
): NonArrayType<X> {
  return '' as any; // Doesn't matter
}

// Drops type error
const test6 = useWithoutArray(new ClassA<{ id: number; name: string }>());
```

I get a

```
Type 'ClassA<{ id: number; name: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'ClassA<Record<string, any>>'.
```

type Error. In some way it makes sense but in theory `{ id: number; name: string; }` is `Record<string, any>`.

The wired thing is that it works with a minified example in a [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-ZZkOTj5jGYTxiBHaro8G7ZmE+aIY6yGpjuJ57nmR67me844UuHZdr6vaQehYbQJh0ZutuU4zthwEUSuDwZtBm6HvhbFwaG-Gsae2GXteCh3tMRD6PA0DJOWEF1hAyAAOqmK4f4EKgAAauEwNpqCoaQE5UT2gzWixx4zrQtAGGEDZ4uI+kTghzB2OI2kGrpbyOIK8DYJo1oAEQhZQMCNDeUkyXJClKTRKnqZpKjYPARn6ZxMAGCZh7mcp1kkXY9mOcgznQPpLCeU+ajeTIel+SwAVBaF4WQJQNDRXemLQKKfWOrKZh0tAGjYMkDpgDyV5sH1s1zaKUmqOo8kaOmfhNoSaaPJUNT2SFKAzCFditEtGjEQRcwAPKaCZ4gmagVDYDkXBBlu50zn4ACySCuJ4qLzCoOQGHY0BvCq0BRhtW1oI9z2vQYADMIPiAJp6yAxbTfPJx6bPA+WWetyCbflNHAydWMjSQwC8NOwAkwTFBQ-TQz0LwcwXk9L2aAANNAVBgDkyDXFUdLhPZx1SQ+2kfiQLCnfJhRSvAvNK4qKuDQj6saAjAD6KpuhQ2CqRpbjaQYhSrSgvOo9W1uidW10mbzEBUzT-DM1QtQS3eD4-q+eoy8gcsU0rAAsfhG8lbipelb4EAYNtXTd3He-LLiDQArBHxspWlZs4ys+NqKnIeDQAbNnUeuDHZsu-0bt0z6FnFx894IvNHed1381ST1s0DRoNTQPaNplCP3cLXexgoJoqTAKQAAKQYQGo0CmnzAtCyNNx0q0bBgNUW+w1ze-QCArJIJZws1F1MrQFMfi2iP+2DSFrR300FBPw6Jnv-EgiPzHg6JemgV5UFbg+CeUCJ5AA).. but not in my framework

Here is the actual issue:
https://github.com/agile-ts/agile/issues/76

Thanks

Comment: Please share reproducable code. Collection ?

Comment: yeah sry.. with Collection I meant 'classA'

Answer (score 0):

Is it fixed in [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDC5QIIB4AqAaaA1aBTAHgC64B2AJjAEq7AD2ATmchIfQJYkDm6qAfNAF5o1Oo2asO3PvwDeAKGjQ6JFvQCuwQgwAU9XGDK0SIAJ7QAbmBBrcALiwBKGQF85ruYRMAHXNAByRoj09GAmqN64aPxCqHhEpBRwCBAoHABmuPTQAKr8APw5ANoAutC20CS45pkA3HJyAPQN0Ki4LNBpaiSabEbQWv1thP0AFr4A5AEkQSFhEeP9EXIEXgzDnd2EvSTQahC4AOpshCO0aoQzoWjoABpxxOQw8JApUbzaCtBkuF4Q5TdyBzlKaXOY%20ZA3WSfPSENT0HbjBaQaBgEgmGrQJrQAAitDaJHGwwAtmBCMR6G56ljsfRaL9Fj48MEGHJlO1iCwAGyCXb7I4nM4XYKhbSVADuSReKFRJkwMmgbDI5RIaiJACNahUwES7NBVJJoM53jJFbYAMzoEjauwAIgAVrQRiQbc4HA4MUA) or did you mean something else? It's a shame not to provide a minimal reproducible example if it is this simple as people can get their teeth into it if they can see the error right there. I had to do a lot of imagining what you meant. Anyway the below has no compile errors.

```
class ClassA<T, V extends Record<string,T> = Record<string,T>> {
  constructor(readonly value:V){}
}

type NonArrayType<T> = T extends ClassA<infer U> ? U[] : never;

// Test function to test the 'NonArrayType' type
export function useWithoutArray<T,X extends ClassA<T>>(
  deps: X
): NonArrayType<X> {
  return '' as any; // Doesn't matter
}

// Drops type error
const test6 = useWithoutArray(new ClassA<any, { id: number; name: string }>({id:3,name:"john"}));
```

Comment: Yeah.. the problem is.. that it works in the playground (see issue, link is to long to paste) quite fine.. but in my framework it drops the error and idk why..
You example doesn't work at all since it returns any and not `{ id: number; name: string }[]` but I guess thats because of my leak of describing the issue properly. thanks

Comment: Sometimes I have an issue if I am picking up tsc from somewhere random and not using the typescript version I think I am. Recent versions compile things that older versions don't.

Comment: yeah sure.. might be worth a look.. I spent some time configuring these and I target `ES2015` and use `commonjs` as module

Comment: ok I found a workaround by simply specifying the value type the `useWithoutArray` function takes  from  `ClassA` to `ClassA<any>`.. now typescript is happy